# How to add element-ui (now called element-plus) to Vue3 project?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, element-ui, element-plus

I have been using "element-ui" and now moving forward to new version of Vue3.
Seems they published a new version called "element-plus" but the tutorial is not updated.

```
import Vue from 'vue';  // not working in Vue3
import ElementUI from 'element-plus';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
...

Vue.use(ElementUI);  // no "Vue" in Vue3 anymore
...
createApp(App).mount('#app') // the new project creation
```

https://element-plus.org/#/en-US/component/quickstart

Anyone manged to do it right and it works?

Comment: Please take a look on the vue3 migration guide: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api.html#a-note-for-plugin-authors

Comment: it just don't work... sorry

Comment: What did you try? `const app = creatApp(App); app.use(ElementUI)` ?

Comment: I have got the same issue. @AngularOne did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vue 3 you need to import `createApp` as well as css from 'element-plus/...' folder. Then you instance your `app` using the vue function imported, basically you pass your main app component to the function as an argument:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './YourMainApp.vue'

import ElementPlus from 'element-plus'
import 'element-plus/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
    
let app = createApp(App)
app.use(ElementPlus)
    
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it very easy without any js bundler.

Here is a sample:

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
          message: 'Hello World!'
      }
    },
    methods: {
        click()  {
          console.log('click()');
        }          
    }
};
const app = Vue.createApp(Main);
app.use(ElementPlus);
app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/element-plus/theme-chalk/index.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.full.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <el-button type="primary" size="medium" @click="click">{{message}}</el-button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```